# Python array elements swap evaluation

Tags: python

My intention is to swap elements in the list, and it works:

```
arr = [4,3,2,1,0]
idx = arr[0]
arr[0], arr[idx] = arr[idx], arr[0]
print(arr)
>> [0, 3, 2, 1, 4]
```

However this does not:

```
arr = [4,3,2,1,0]
arr[0], arr[arr[0]] = arr[arr[0]], arr[0]
print(arr)
>> [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

How python evaluates the latter example?

Comment: The mere fact that there ARE multiple ways to interpret that statement is the reason you should not use it.  C++ would call it "undefined behavior".  In this case, the behavior is well-defined, but unexpected.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier to see what's happening if you split the assignment into multiple statements.

```
arr[0], arr[arr[0]] = arr[arr[0]], arr[0]
```

is equivalent to:

```
temp = arr[arr[0]], arr[0] # temp = (0, 4)
arr[0] = temp[0]           # arr[0] = 0
arr[arr[0]] = temp[1]      # arr[0] = 4
```

Notice that `arr[0]` is being updated before we assign to `arr[arr[0]]`. That updated index is being used in the last assignment.

None of this ever reassigns `arr[4]`, so it doesn't swap the two elements.

Answer (score 2):

Let's use the walrus operator (`:=`) to gain some insight into what's happening.

```
>>> arr = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> arr[0], arr[a := arr[0]] = arr[b := arr[0]], arr[0]
>>> arr
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> a
0
>>> b
4
```

Now if we rework this slightly:

```
>>> arr = [4,3,2,1,0]
>>> arr[0], arr[b] = arr[b := arr[0]], arr[0]
>>> print(arr)
[0, 3, 2, 1, 4]
```

What's happening is similar to the unexpected behavior programmers see when modifying a collection *while iterating over it*.

Answer (score 2):

Right side values are all evaluated and saved to temporary space before assignments proceed from left to right.  So the value of arr[0] gets assigned before the next assignment to arr[arr[0]] which makes the receiving position different from the original value you had in arr[0] (i.e. it gets set to zero before being used in arr[arr[0]].

If you reverse the order of assignment so that arr[0] is modified after being used in arr[arr[0]] you will get the expected result:

```
arr[arr[0]], arr[0] =  arr[0], arr[arr[0]]
```

Still this remains tricky as it depends on the data and shouldn't be something you use in real life programs.